# Entities with Foreign Key references to phantom tables & entities

Tags: sql, jpa

I have an existent legacy DDL which I've to map onto JPA.

I've already mapped the USERS SQL table to an USERS JPA @Entity.

```
create table USERS (
  -- a bunch of fields
  primary key (id),
  foreign key FK_USERS_CONTACT (CONTACT_ID) references CONTACTS(ID),
  foreign key USER_SPEAKS_NATIVE_LANGUAGE (NATIVE_LANGUAGE) references LANGUAGES(ID),
  foreign key USER_HAS_PREFERRED_TIMEZONE (PREF_TIMEZONE_ID) references TIME_ZONES(ID),
  foreign key USER_OWNS_USAGE (USAGE_OWNER_ID) references USAGE_OWNERS(ID)
);
```

But there are those FKs to existent SQL tables that I don't want to depict in any JPA classes. The best solution would be to do the following:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(nullable = false, name = "USAGE_OWNER_ID")
private Object usageOwners;
```

...basically to use a **dummy/phantom Object** that could reflect any table reference. But the raw Object type isn't allowed in JPA.

So how can *I depict & fulfill the Foreign Key constraints of the USERS table without depicting any SQL tables in JPA*. I just want to **depict the FK references to those tables but not the actual SQL tables**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be best off having a Contact, Language, TimeZone, UsageOwner class.  If you do want to have classes, then you could just have a @Basic mapping for the foreign key and map it as a basic type such as Integer.